# C hex constant type

Tags: c, gcc

I wrote the following c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
  printf("%d\n", -1 >> 8);
  return 0;
}
```

I compile this code with gcc 4.6.3 on my x86_64 using the -m32 flag. I get -1 printed out as I would expect, the shift occurs arithmetically using two's complement representation resulting in -1.

Now if I instead write

```
printf("%d\n", 0xFFFFFFFF >> 8);
```

I get 16777215. I would have expected this constant to be interpreted as an int (signed) and then the shift to be arithmetic which would result in -1 again. I've looked through the latest C standard and I can't seem to understand why this is the case. Any ideas?

Comment: It's the difference between signed (-1) and unsigned (0xFFFFFFFF)

Comment: @SpacedMonkey I'm asking why 0xFFFFFFFF is unsigned

Comment: @SpacedMonkey Btw, `-` does not contribute to this difference. `-` is still a unary operator and it does not make something signed. It's `1` that's signed (and therefore `-1` is signed as well), while `0xFFFFFFFF` is unsigned.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the C99 standard (6.4.4.1), hexadecimal constants will be the first type on this list that can represent them:

```
int
unsigned int
long int
unsigned long int
long long int
unsigned long long int
```

The hex literal `0xFFFFFFFF` does not fit in an `int` (which can hold the values `-0x80000000` to `0x7FFFFFFF`), but does fit in `unsigned int`, and therefore its type will be unsigned. Right-shifting the unsigned value `0xFFFFFFFF` by 8 gives `16777215`.

Comment: Why doesn't 0xFFFFFFFF fit in an int?

Comment: @dschatz: Because it's 4294967295, and your `int` can only go up to 2147483647.

Comment: @dschatz: I just edited to add - Because it's more than 0x7fffffff which is the largest value representable by a 32-bit int using 2's complement representation.

Comment: Because 0xFFFFFFFF is written as unsigned, and if you stick it into an int it would end up being -1

Comment: @ChristianStieber: That's not generally true. Conversion to signed is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 11):

Undecorated integral literals have different type depending on whether they are decimal or not (6.4.4.1/5 in C11, Table 6 in C++11):

- decimal literals, i.e. `[1-9][0-9]*`, are always signed.
- hexadecimal and octal literals are either signed or unsigned. If the value is to large for a signed type, but small enough to fit the unsigned type of the same width, it will be unsigned. (This is what happens to your hex constant.)

Right-shifting negative integers is implementation-defined, and you happen to get sign-extension. Right-shifting the unsigned value is simple division by two.

Comment: The C standard draft I found here http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf shows that hex constants are ints before unsigned ints on page 64. What am I missing?

Comment: What you said does not match the C99 standard (6.4.4.1/5). According to that decimal constants are signed and hex/octal may be signed or unsigned.

Comment: @dschatz: Oh, I got it the wrong way round. Let me fix! It's indeed the same in C++ and C.