# Why is 0XAA an unsigned int and not an int?

Tags: c

I saw this from *C Primer Plus, the 6th edition*, Review Questions in Chapter 3.

The question:

[image: Question Picture]

Answer in Appendix A:

[image: Answer Picture]

Notice d.0XAA, my answer is `int` constant, hexadecimal format, But the answer is `unsigned int`

and I wonder why

Comment: That's how the language defines it. Someone at some point decided that's how it should be. You can't really find out why unless you have a time machine and can ask whoever made that decision a few decades ago.

Comment: @Art could you please to give more information from C standard or something else? I'll appreciate that:)

Comment: Here's the reference you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499592/c-hex-constant-type

Comment: `unsigned int` is correct only if `sizeof(int) > 1`. `int` is always correct as well as `char`.

Comment: C11 standard §6.4.4.1

Comment: Wait a minute. That paragraph of the standard contradicts me. I might be wrong.

Comment: It seems to me that answer in that book is wrong. `0xAA` is always representable with `int`, so there is no reason for it to be `unsigned int`.

Comment: Hmm, no, it is `int`, mouviciel got it backwards.  Making it unsigned requires 0xAAU.

Comment: I take back everything I said. Apparently I've always believed wrongly that hexadecimal constants are always unsigned. They aren't. The book is wrong.

Comment: @Art Thank you very much :)

Comment: Why the down vote? Spotting bugs in well-known programming books as a beginner is pretty impressive.

Comment: @Art Hex constants are always treated as non-negative values.  Given that, I'm not sure that there's any way that assumption could hurt.  Is there any way for there to be a difference in logical and arithmetic shift operations for non-negative values?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Non-negative values by themselves isn't the problem, but the signed type and implicit type promotions. You'd get problems if you for example did something like `(my_unsigned_char & 0xAA) << 31` as opposed to `(my_unsigned_char & 0xAAu) << 31`. The former invokes undefined behavior, the latter is perfectly fine code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That book is incorrect. As per C11 6.4.4.1, the type of integer constants of hexadecimal are determined from this table:

```
Suffix    ...    Octal or Hexadecimal Constant

None      ...    int
                 unsigned int
                 long int
                 unsigned long int
                 long long int
                 unsigned long long int

u or U    ...    unsigned int
                 unsigned long int
                 unsigned long long int
```

Your constant `0xAA` has no suffix so the top part of the above table is what applies. Meaning: the compiler will first check if the value can fit in an `int`. If it doesn't fit, it will check if it will fit in an `unsigned int` and so on.

On any known implementation of C, the value `0xAA` will certainly fit inside an `int`. The correct answer to the question is `int`.

However, had the constant been `0xAAu`, the bottom part of the cited table would have applied and the result would have been an `unsigned int`.

Comment: To add to an answer, since standard requires that `INT_MAX` is at least `+32767`, all hexadecimal constants without suffix from `0x0` to `0x7fff` are always `int`.

Comment: This wasn't listed among the known errata, so I've submitted an errata to the publisher.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerely^_^